# Counterintuitive results with violinplot

Tags: r, violin-plot

I created a violinplot using the following code
the variables are holdingtime (the time a position has been held for)
and realgain (binary and 1 if the position is a gain and 0 otherwise)

```
realtrans %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=realgain, y=logtime,group=realgain)) + 
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE, position="dodge", alpha=.3) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("holding time") +
  ylim(0,8) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult = 1),
               geom="pointrange", color="darkgreen",
               shape = 18, size = 0.75,
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

The result was not quiete what I expected:

[image]

Does any part of this code remove outlieres or change the data in a way I am not aware of?

The results for a t test (for the means) look like this
[image]

Why then is the mean for holdingtime under the condition realgain = 1 higher?
Am I overlooking something?

Comment: `ylim` filters the data and then calculates summary statistics.  `coord_cartesian` calculates statistics and then "zooms" the plots.  Whether this is something you are not aware of, I cannot say.

Comment: Also, means of 62 and 20 in your screenshot are inconsistent with your y axis limits.  Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: You plotted realtrans$logtime in y-axis which you changed in "holding time", whereas in your test you compared realtrans$holdingtime with realtrans$realgain, so it does not match